# How to disable the whole view while fetching a request?

Tags: iphone, uiview, nsmutableurlrequest

I am working with a iPhone application in which I am displaying images in a scroll view.

The "Gallery" feature is working nicely but In an exceptional condition I want the view locked untill I get the images loaded .

So the question is how can I disable the view and show it slightly blurred while I am fetching the images .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt Gallagher has a great reusable [Loading View](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html) example on his site under a very generous, open license.

If it's not exactly what you want, it's probably pretty close.  He documents it well, and talks about the design very nicely in the post.